# c# файл открывается не зная своего каталога

Tags: c#

Пишу форму открытия программы на c# в visual studio
при клике на кнопку должен открываться exe файл
структура программы такая
-update (в папке update лежит файл: version.txt и run.exe)
-start.exe(файл собранного решения
При нажатии на кнопку открывается файл run.exe и выдаёт ошибку, что не видит файла version.txt,
то есть он думает, что он в каталоге рядом со start.exe

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Updater
{
    public partial class Updater_z : Form
    {
        public Updater_z()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            string relPath = @"update\run.exe";
            string relPath1 = @"update\";
            //Console.WriteLine(path + relPath);

            
            ;
            //MessageBox.Show(path + relPath);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + relPath);
           

        }
    }
}
```

как мне заставить работать корректно подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы не ту программу привели в вопросе. Проблема-то в запускаемой, а не в запускаторе.

Comment: Ну, на стороне запускатора можно рабочую директорию указать, но если обе программы выше -и чинить надо именно запускаемую программу.

Comment: Тип приложения? Версия дотнета? К чему относится показанный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запускаемой программе установите текущий рабочий каталог с помощью

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory =
```

Comment: да это помогло спасибо, я а самой кнопке чуть выше запуска добавил Environment.CurrentDirectory = relPath1;